# Не скачивается библиотека win32gui для python

Tags: python, pip, win32gui

Пытаюсь скачать библиотеку `win32gui` через расширение `pip manager` в `vs code`, но выдаёт такую ошибку:

> error: subprocess-exited-with-error

```
   Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.   exit
 code: 1
      [19 lines of output]   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py",
 line 353, in <module>
       main()
     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py",
 line 335, in main
       json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py",
 line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
       return hook(config_settings)
     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mthdbe6x\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py",
 line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
       return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mthdbe6x\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py",
 line 323, in _get_build_requires
       self.run_setup()
     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mthdbe6x\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py",
 line 487, in run_setup
       super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mthdbe6x\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py",
 line 338, in run_setup
       exec(code, locals())
     File "<string>", line 27, in <module>
     File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xiboye2f\win32gui_8bf93f1fc8b24fc79d8bcb4ec74de10d\win32\distutils\gui.py",
 line 6, in <module>
       from .command import win32_build_ext   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32.distutils.command'   [end of output]
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: subprocess-exited-with-error
 
 Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully. exit
 code: 1
 
 See above for output.
 
 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
 problem with pip.
```

Пытался найти решение проблемы, но так и не нашёл... Подскажите, как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Установите pywin32

`pip install pywin32`